# почему метод @Test класс HomePage подсвечивает обьект home как не опознанный?

Tags: java

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;


public class GoogleTestPage {
    private FirefoxDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void setUp (){
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("http://google.com");

    }

    @After
    public void tearDown(){
        driver.close();
    }

    @Test
    public void testSearch(){
        HomePage home  = new  HomePage(driver);
        ResultPage result  = home.search("automated testing info");
        assertTrue(result.getFirstLink().contains("automated"));
    }

}
```

Comment: а где находится класс HomePage? А как он выглядит? А почему его тут нет? как подсвечивается home? а что говорит?

Comment: он есть реализую pageobjectmodel

Comment: Где есть? Покажите его полный код.

Comment: судя по импортированным классам. осмелюсь предположить, что HomePage  не импортирован.

Comment: Нужно точно указать сообщение об ошибке, «подсветки» недостаточно.

Comment: Note. This element has no attached Javadoc and the Javadoc could not found in the attached source

Comment: org.junit.Test вроде все правильно сделал

Comment: не понимаю почему не работает